# Power BI Call Out Overlapping Times by Date

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I have a table that is for timestamps.    [Table w/ Columns] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEjhI.png)

I need a way to call out when times overlap on the same date.

| Date | Start Time | Stop Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9/29 | 7:52:10 | 7:54:15 |
| 9/29 | 7:52:11 | 7:53:25 |
| 9/30 | 7:53:09 | 7:54:07 |

First line, the punch starts at 7:52 and doesn't end until 7:54, second line the new punch also starts at 7:52, which is not allowed since the previous stamp wasn't stopped yet. There cannot be concurrent times.

It also needs to be isolated by date, so the 9/30 punch of 7:53 would not factor into this.

Originally, I did the below code until I saw it was only focused on the punches and not the date of punch.

I concatenated the date and time columns with two new columns named MergedStart and MergedStop

I did a bunch of variations of this code in terms of MergedStart  and MergedStop placement thinking I only cared about the Start Times I repeated it in the comparison. (note I did change the column names in my actual codes I just didn't want to retype from my very original try)

```
Column = 
VAR start_date = TS[StartTime]
VAR end_date = TS[StopTime]
VAR _index = TS[StartTime]
RETURN
IF (
    ISBLANK (
        COUNTX (
            FILTER (
                TS,
                (
                       start_date >=TS[StartTime]
                        && start_date <= TS[StartTime]
                )
                    && [StartTime] <> _index
            ),
            [StopTime]
        )
    ),
    "NoConflict",
    "Conflict")
```

Then I started to do this

```
(StartDate1 <= EndDate2) and (StartDate2 <= EndDate1)
```

but I do not have 4 columns to compare, it would be by the rows based off MergedStart and MergedStop. I tried just  (StartDate1 <= EndDate2) which obviously didn't work